# Diagonalization of Integral Kernel

Tags: functional-analysis

Say I have an integral kernel $K(x,y)$  over some space $\Omega \times \Omega$, and in the case I'm specifically interested in, $K(x,y)$ is a stochastic integral kernel. But I'd like to apply this operator many times, and with what may be a somewhat novel view of considering the integral kernel a "continuous matrix", it seems reasonable to try and iterate such kernels via eigendecomposition. So, in a way very much analogous to finite matrices, I'll explain what I hope to do.

The multiplication of two Kernels we define as $$K_2 \times K_1 (u, v) = \int_{\Omega} K_2(u,r) K_1(r,v) \ \text{d}r$$

The identity kernel can be defined simply as $$I_{\Omega}(u,v) = \delta_u^v $$

So the inverse of a kernel is a kernel so that $$ K \times K^{-1} = I_\Omega $$

Now, I'd like to understand $K^n = \prod_{k=1}^n K$ by using eigenfunctions $\eta(x,y) = \eta_x (y)$ where $\{ \eta_x \} |_{x \in \Omega }$ is the set of all of these eigenfunctions and there corresponding eigenvalues where we write $$\xi(x,y) = \begin{cases} \lambda_x & x=y \\ 0 & x \neq y \end{cases}$$ So an eigenfunction is a continuous analog of an eigenvector with $$\int_{\Omega} K(u,v)f(u) \ \text{d}u = \lambda f(v) $$ with something like $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. If I could find such an infinite basis of eigenfunctions, then I simply write $$K = \eta \times \xi \times \eta^{-1} \Rightarrow K^n = \eta \times \xi^n \times \eta^{-1} $$ by the same cancellation  property we have in the matrix case. And of course $\xi$ is easily to exponentiate because $$ \xi^n(x,y) = (\xi(x,y))^n $$ I think this might work but I don't have a good idea how one might go about finding $\eta$ and $\xi$.

It certainly seems natural to write that we need some nontrivial function to satisfy the eigenfunction equation $$(K - \lambda I_{\Omega}) f = 0 $$ and thus it suffices to understand when $$\ker K - \lambda I_\Omega $$ is nontrivial. Since we'd like this to happen at least the cardinality of the conntinuum many times (since we hope they generate a kernel) perhaps it's the case that there are solutions for something like almost all or all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text{ or } \mathbb{C}$, and perhaps if $\Omega$ is higher dimensional then each eigenvalue has a large basis of eigenfunction, I don't know.

So, I'd like to know if there is (and I presume there is) a way to eigendecompose Fredholm operators or more sepcifically integral kernels. Or, if it's somehow done differently, if there is some way to exponentiate integral kernels.

Comment: You're [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Origins_in_integral_equation_theory) (most importantly, the spectrum is at most countable, but this should not disappoint you).

Comment: @metamorphy I am most definitely there, that's very useful. If you answer with that I can accept it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. When $\Omega$ has finite measure, stochastic kernels indeed lead to compact operators, but other cases may be complicated. But even in the "compact" case, the question of "diagonalizability" is far from being clear - that's why I don't even try to write an answer.